# How to import data from csv to postgresql table that has an auto_increment first column or field

Tags: postgresql, csv, pgadmin-4

Hi I am trying to import data to a postgresql table from a csv file, so I'd like to know how do I exlude the first column since it is an identity column that increments when data is inserted?

**Error I get is here**

[image: Error I get is here]

Comment: By writing out all the other columns(in the csv file field order) in the `COPY` column list. Then the incoming `CSV` fields will match those columns you want data inserted into.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some script to add or modify data, then you should just skip the variable on the script (e.g. does not write then on the insert statement), but on doing so you should modify your csv to delete the insert column(the data, if any, and the separator, usually a comma) since the number of variables are now different.
Looking at your print I suppose you are using pgadmin or some simmilar GUI, on the case of pgadmin if you click on the column and select the import\export data... option, you will open a windows where you should select "import" and then, on the upper windows menu, click on "columns" and exclude the "ID" or any other auto-increment, this slution also needs you to remove the csv column as well.